Using rosbag C++ API in a non-ROS application
I have a standalone / "non-ROS" C++ application that is built using cmake.
I want to extend this application with the ability to write data to .bag files.
The goal is to use the existing C++ rosbag API to write these files.
Is it possible to use the C++ rosbag API in my non-ROS C++ application while keeping my cmake based build system? I want to avoid having to change my entire build process "just" to use the C++ rosbag API.
